# I am trying to integrate a like functionality into a blog I built bus it seems not to be working

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

what I want the code to do is to push into the array Likes if the userId is not in the array and if it is already in the array its should return response already liked or perform unlike which I am yet to ryt but it is not even pushing to the array
this is the error I am getting:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'postTitle')

```
app.post("/post/:postId", function (req, res) {
  const postId = req.params.postId;
  const userId = req.user.id;

  User.findOne({ "posts._id": postId }, function (err, foundUser) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      const post = foundUser.post.id(postId);
      if(!post){
        res.redirect('/')
      }else if (post.likes.includes(userId)) {
        res.redirect("/post/" + encodeURIComponent(post.postTitle));
      } else {
        post.likes.push(userId);
        foundUser.save(function () {
          res.redirect("/post/" + encodeURIComponent(post.postTitle));
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: you are checking for negative check on the first if statement `if(!post){` it should be `if(post)` to check if the is not null and read it's content on the next else code blocks

Comment: Are you using Sequelize or something else?

Comment: @ZemichaelTesfaye that doesn't make sense? `!null // true`

Comment: @ZemichaelTesfaye It does not look like that behavior is what he wants.

Comment: my bad @evolutionxbox and PooloverNathan

Comment: @DareAce It would be helpful to state which line you are getting the error on and to show your database schema.

Comment: I struggle to see how this code could give that error. The only place `postTitle` is read (well two places) it is from `post` and there is a test `if (!post)` that would stop it reaching those places if it was null.

Comment: Is post an embed of user? Interesting choice. Will probably bite you later.

Comment: @PoolloverNathan so I tried out `if (post)` and now it is returning a new error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'likes')

Comment: @DareAceRex That would stop processing if the post *exists*, which doesn't look like what you want. Zemichael and Drew are incorrect. Please see my previous comment.

Comment: @PoolloverNathan I am not using sequelize, what I want is when the click button is clicked in the DB the Likes is updated with the userID, do you get?

Comment: @DareAceRex what line is it throwing that error? There are 2 references to postTitle

Comment: @DrewGallagher   post.likes.push(userId); here checking for the null value `if (!post)` the array is not updated

Comment: @DareAceRex can you give me the exact line that the error is being thrown? What code statement is on the line where the error is being thrown?

Comment: @DrewGallagher `post.likes.push(userID)` line 12

Comment: ok cool. @DareAceRex can you console.log(post) and show me the the output at that line?

Comment: **null** @DrewGallagher

Comment: ok so that means the if(!post) check is not working as expected. can you change that to 

if(post != null){ 

and let me know if it changes the output?

Comment: @DrewGallagher same **TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'likes')**

Comment: @DareAceRex My conclusion is that your computer is haunted.

Comment: @DareAceRex that error is a different property and a different line now, which is good. Can you tell me which line that's being thrown?

Answer (score -2):

Since post.postTitle is giving you a `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'postTitle')`, that means that the `post` you are trying to get the `postTitle` from is `null`.

add a null check to see if that post is null first and handle that properly

```
if(post != null){
```

also `console.log(post)` and see what you are getting.

it might be coming back undefined so that check would not be correct.

then you would have to check if it's not undefined

Comment: `if(!post){` should cover that already.

Comment: That is already implemented with the `if(!post){` line.

Comment: @PoolloverNathan if that was the case it wouldn't be entering that block, but it is still. The question is which block is it failing at, since postTitle is referenced multiple times